# Debugging Selenium and Chromedriver on AWS Lambda (chrome not reachable)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, serverless

I've got a Lambda Function for headless chrome + python selenium deployed with Serverless framework that runs fine locally but crashes on lambda.

Some basic details:
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.14.231-180.360.amzn2.x86_64 x86_64)

Chromium Version: 89xx
selenium==3.141.0

Here is how i'm invoking it with selenium:

```
options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        #'/opt/chromedriver' not found
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

    driver.get('https://www.neaminational.org.au/')
    body = f"Headless Chrome Initialized, Page title: {driver.title}"

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": body
    }
```

I'm getting the cryptic Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(chrome not reachable)
(The process started from chrome location /opt/headless-chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.).

Now i've tested this on my ubuntu 18 (same chromium binary, same chrome driver, same install selenium version) and it's working fine... so my issue must be with compatibility with the lambda amz linux environment.

Can anyone give me some idea on how i could troubleshoot this?  Seems silly to stumble around trying different versions when they all seem compatible with eachother locally.

Any insight appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be really helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWqbYiHudt8

https://github.com/soumilshah1995/Selenium-on-AWS-Lambda-Python3.7

The versions are the following:

```
RUNTIME=python3.7

SELENIUM_VER=3.141.0
CHROME_BINARY_VER=v1.0.0-55 # based on Chromium 69.0.3497.81
CHROMEDRIVER_VER=2.43       # supports Chrome v69-71
```

Credits go to Soumil Nitin Shah.

Best,

Ramón